# Get a column total and a GROUP BY total

Tags: mysql, sql, join, group-by, aggregate-functions

In SQL I want to get what % of site hits came from each user. To do this I need to get the sum of the column `site hits`, but my query uses a GROUP By on another column.

How can I get a sum for the entire column, in addition to each user_id in the GROUP BY?

Data set:

```
User    Page Hits    Page
----    ---------    ----
a       10           home
a       10           profile
b       8            home
b       2            profile
c       6            home
c       4            profile
```

Result:

```
User     Site Hits      pct of total site hits
----     ---------      ---------------
a        20             50%
b        10             25%
c        10             25%
```

Query:

```
SELECT
user,
SUM(page_hits) AS site_hits,
SUM(page_hits) / total_page_hits <-- How do I get sum of 'page hits' for total_page_hits ????
FROM hit_data
GROUP BY user
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option: use a subquery.

```
SELECT
user,
SUM(page_hits) AS site_hits,
SUM(page_hits) / (select sum(page_hits) from hit_data) 
FROM hit_data
GROUP BY user
```

Comment: Can you use a subquery in the way you've shown it? I thought a subquery had to be part of the FROM or JOIN statement?

Comment: Yes, this is the proper way as I alluded to. Subqueries can be used in the JOIN/WHERE or in the SELECT as a column.

Comment: Nope, it can be used to return scalars pretty much anywhere in a query.

Comment: Is this less efficient than having it in the FROM or JOIN clause?

Comment: No, it's perfectly efficient. The optimizer will just run that subquery one time and then use that value for all the rest of the data. The performance will be identical to joining that value into the main query.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you do a subquery where you select the total hits as a column from a subquery you'll need to do this as two queries.

Comment: The problem with a JOIN is that you proliferate the number of rows before the group by, and then the total for the page hits would be effected.

Answer (score 0):

This might work and it's more reasonable than it might seem:

```
SELECT user, SUM(page_hits) AS site_hits,
       SUM(page_hits) / (select sum(page_hits) from hit_data)
FROM hit_data
GROUP BY user
```

Since the sub-query is not correlated to the record, the database engine can first run the sub-query, then use it as a constant in the outer query.